# Styling child elements depending on html order without css ids or class

Tags: css

There are two scenarios possible. Firstly the `<p>` could come before the `<img>` tag

```
<a>
   <p></p>
   <img></img>
<a>
```

and secondly it could come after

```
<a>
   <img></img>
   <p></p>
<a>
```

I was wondering if there is any way to target the `<p>` element in both situations and style them differently.

I would like to position the `<p>` to the left if it comes before the `<img>` or right if it comes after.

I need to this be without adding any CSS classes / IDs to any elements.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select all img very next a p with the selector +

```
p + img{
    ...
}
```

In the same way you can style all p after an img

```
img + p{
     ...
}
```

For Style the p as first child:

```
a > p:first-child{
   ...
}
```

More info on http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp
and 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

Comment: :first-child is okeay but i prefer nth-of-type.  good entry of the 'plus selector' but not for this case...

Answer (score 1):

Use [nth-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp), is supported and you can do

```
    a > p:nth-child(2) {
       float:right;
    }
    a > p:nth-child(1) {
       float:left;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see many people here do not understand :nth-xxxxxx

google for:

```
:nth-of-type(x);
```

```css
span > b:nth-of-type(1) {
  /*meaning first b direct child of span*/
  background-color: rgba(255, 13, 55, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<span>
  <s>p</s>
<b>b</b>
<i>i</i>
  <b>b</b>
</span>
<br>

<span>
  <b>b</b>
<i>i</i>
<s>p</s>
    <b>b</b>
    <b>b</b>
</span>
<br>
<span>
  <b>b</b>
<s>p</s>
<i>i</i>
    <b>b</b>
</span>
```